# Michael Hartl rails tutorial chapter 8 sign out not working in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm following a tutorial by Michael Hartl. I'm implementing chapter 8, which is the sign in and sign out process. I have the app deployed to Heroku.

The tutorial has account dropdown box in header that is supposed to roll down and show the link sign out when clicked. When I deploy the app locally, the dropwdown box drops and shows the link when I click it. However, after I deploy the app to Heroku, the dropdown box doesn't drop when I click it, and the URL is appended with `#` at the end.

There are many files (controllers, models, etc.), so I don't know which one I should post here. The codes are almost verbatim of what is in the book.

Comment: start with the code that has deviated from the code that's in the book - it's likely that your mistake is somewhere in there

Comment: It sounds like you haven't run `rake assets:precompile`. Any time the  css or javascript changes you will need to run this.

Comment: @ZachKemp, I ran assets:precompile (even after deleting all the precompiled assets), and no luck :(

I accidentally tumbled across a post with same problem last night, and the comment given (that solved the problem) was:
The bootstrap javascript library added into application.js file need to be placed directly underneath the jquery library.
So instead of:
`//=require jquery
//=require jquery_ujs
//=require bootstrap`

It should be:
`//=require jquery
//=require bootstrap
//=require jquery_ujs`

The order in the book is not right.

Comment: That solves my problem. Should i answer my own question? and maybe not a bad idea to warn michael hartl about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally tumbled across a post with same problem last night, and the comment given (that solved the problem) was: The bootstrap javascript library added into application.js file need to be placed directly underneath the jquery library. 
So instead of:  
`//=require jquery

//=require jquery_ujs

//=require bootstrap`

It should be: 
`//=require jquery

//=require bootstrap

//=require jquery_ujs`

Comment: A lot of nagging little problems with that tutorial.